# Find the maximum number of columns in Excel that have entries (Python)

Tags: python, excel

For the maximum number of rows, I am able to use

`from openpyxl import *
max_row = len(file)`

Is there something similarly simple for maximum columns? I can do a while loop and check if it's empty but this seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert file into csv and read it through pandas

As you want to calculate columns without missing values first remove columns with no entries.

```
df=df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

Then print

```
print(len(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `max_column()` function returns the maximum column.

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
worksheet = book.get_sheet_by_name(all_worksheets[0])
total_column = worksheet.max_column()
```